# How to force Date calculation in RPGLE to use ISO date and prevent RNX0114 error

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a weird problem with a date calculation in RPG. I am trying to convert Excel style date (number of days since 1900) to date. This is the code I am trying:

```
dcl-proc EXCELtoDate;
  dcl-pi *n date(*iso);
    datein packed(6:0);
  end-pi;

  if datein > 59;
    return d'1899-12-30' + %days(datein);
  else;
    return d'1899-12-31' + %days(datein);
  endif;

end-proc;
```

I receive an error RNX0114 if the date is less than 1940. Which I would understand if I was using a two digit year (*YMD, *DMY, *MDY, *JUL) as per IBM specs, but I am not anywhere. So I am not sure why the calculation is done using two digit format or how to force it to use four digit year.

Note: the if statement is there to compensate for a known issue where Excel wrongly considers 1900 to be a leap year.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a previous statement that calls the procedure and not the procedure itself. If the statement includes a conversion to a two digit year, the error will be seemingly reported as coming from within the procedure rather than from the statement itself. For example the conversion in the first statement will succeed, but fail in second, while failing on the end-proc statement.

```
gooddate = %char(EXCELtoDate(14609):*usa/);
baddate = %char(EXCELtoDate(14609):*mdy/);

dcl-proc EXCELtoDate;
  dcl-pi *n date(*iso);
    datein packed(6:0);
  end-pi;

  if datein > 59;
    return d'1899-12-30' + %days(datein);
  else;
    return d'1899-12-31' + %days(datein);
  endif;

end-proc;
```